# How can I clear the screen in the MySQL console?

Tags: mysql, command-line

I am not able to clear the screen in the MySQL command line prompt. My screen is filled with tables, data and queries. How can I clear it up?

Comment: You want drop your database?

Comment: try this[link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html) you may get some help

Comment: here works for system clear; for mariaDb

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try your terminal application's screen clear. There is no such thing as a command to clean the MySQL shell.

On a Mac, you can go to menu *Edit* → *Clear Screen* or use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: In iTerm2 it's `Edit > Clear Buffer` or `CMD+K`

Comment: In that case, then how to we shell out? GDB allows us to `shell reset` to clear the terminal. How does one shell out in the MySQL terminal?

Answer (score 165):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

will do it - it's a shell command, but it works well in the MySQL console.

Comment: Yep, this works. The question that was marked as the right answer didn't

Comment: This is not working in windows environment, Please guide

Comment: What does the L mean?

Comment: A good question. It's not often explained. Control + letter is really what ever the ASCII of the letter is minus 64. In this case it's form feed. Form feed is advance to the next page. In the same way control I is the tab char.

Comment: @exussum note for me must in Arch Linux: `ALT+L` and `CTRL+L`

Answer (score 129):

Another possibility is to issue a system command.

For Linux:

```
mysql> system clear;
```

For Windows (I'd guess. For Linux I'm sure though):

```
mysql> system cls;
```

Comment: This is better. Do note that the command depends on the OS where your MySQL CLI is running, not necessarily where you're seated. If you use a Windows laptop to connect to a Linux server and run the CLI there, the command is `clear`. If you install a MySQL CLI in your Windows laptop and connect to a database in the local CLI, the command is `cls`.

Comment: Also worth mentioning: There's no need for the semicolon as it's not an SQL statement. There's a shortcut for `system `; it is `\! `. For example, you can just do `\! clear`.

Comment: On Linux `system clear` scrolls down, hiding scroll back history. `system reset` may be better since it clears the scroll back, too.