# Clear screen in MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client (Windows 10)

Tags: mysql

Can you let me know how to clean the screen (all the queries executed before) in MySQL 5.7 Command Line Client? I'm running Windows 10, and I've tried system clear or system clc comands but it doesen't work.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you trying to clear the terminal screen or are you trying to clear all query history?  have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19376104/how-to-clear-screen-in-mysql#answer-19377096 ?

Comment: I'm trying to clear the terminal screen only.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19376221/10824251

Answer (score 1):

Type <kbd>Control-L</kbd> or enter the command

```
mysql> system cls
```

`cls` is the Windows command to clear the Command Prompt window, not `clear` or `clc`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this.
write a bat file

```
@mysql -uroot -p123456 -D%1 -e%2
```

named it mysqldb.bat.

then  use the bat:

```
mysqldb.bat dbname "select * from tablename;"
cls
```

Answer (score 0):

Use '! reset' this will clear the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I stumbled across it and saw it was still open, and people are still telling you things that don't work. Keep It Simple: just exit, run the cls command, and reenter.
Here's an example in MariaDB:

```
MariaDB[(TestDB)]> exit;
    Bye
C:\...\mysql\bin> cls
C:\...\mysql\bin> mysql -h localhost -u root
MariaDB[(none)]> USE TestDB;
MariaDB[(TestDB)]>
```

Probably not what you were looking for, but it's only a couple short lines to do it.